# Is conversation Id in slack immutable?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to send messages to channels. Documentation give advice to receive all channels, pick you channel by name and after all send message by conversationId.
I want to cache the value of conversation id. But I want to be sure it won't be changed.

Comment: Please share more details. May be the link to the documentation you are referencing to.

Comment: https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending#conversations

Comment: I've tried to use api chatPostMessage just with channel name and it also works well. Why do I need to receive channels at all?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says

> Recently we began preserving the channel ID of channels converted from
> public to private.

So we can conclude, that it is immutable now

https://api.slack.com/changelog/2018-09-more-reasons-to-be-a-conversations-api-convert